# Where is the problem with plotting a graph of function?

Tags: plot, graphs

Why this doesn't work?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz} % package used for the tikz  
\usepackage{pgfplots} % package used to draw plots  
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar} % the polar library is used to implement the negative and positive axis  
\usepgflibrary{shapes.geometric}  
\usetikzlibrary{calc}  
\pgfplotsset{my style/.append style={axis x line=middle, axis y line=  
middle, xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}, axis equal }}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture} % tikz environment   

\begin{axis}  
[my style, xtick={-10,10}, ytick={-10,10}, xmin=-10, xmax=10, ymin=-11, ymax=11]
\addplot[domain=-0.99:10] {-100*(x^5+7*x^4+21*x^3+35*x^2+35*x+141)/(x+1)^7};
\end{axis}  
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I get this error:

! File ended while scanning use of \pgfplots@addplotimpl@expression@curly.\par<> "./MATLAB report.tex"I suspect you have forgotten a '}', causing meto read past where you wanted me to stop.I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,you'd better type 'E' or 'X' now and fix your file.! Emergency stop.<> "./MATLAB report.tex" (job aborted, no legal \end found)Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:23530 strings out of 492452605055 string characters out of 3132156780355 words of memory out of 300000027507 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+20000010132 words of font info for 39 fonts, out of 3000000 for 90001141 hyphenation exceptions out of 819169i,6n,98p,812b,1139s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

How to fix it?

Comment: As always on this site, please provide a full self contained example that others can copy and test on they own systems. Here the code is not self contained as we don't know what `my style` is. Additionally you're missing the mandatory `;` after `\addplot[...]{...};`

Comment: Sure, I uploaded my entire code. Yes, mistake was in `;`, but I have another. It says that i can't divide number with 0

Comment: If you drop `axis equal` the error disappears.

Comment: Yes, thanks for that. But why my graph is strange, it seems to be wrong?